# Is there a problem to use 2 passports, one for getting into country and another whilst coming back?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I am dual national of country X and Y.

When I will be traveling from country X to Y, I want to use country Y's passport.

When I will be coming back to country X from Y, I want to use country X's passport.

Would there be any issues what so ever not just on airports but in future ?

Comment: I’ve voted to close as a duplicate of the question above, I think the answer there should tell you what you want to know. If it doesn’t, feel free to edit this question to clarify the difference (you’ll probably have to specify *which* countries you’re talking about)

Comment: This used to not be a problem at all. Nowadays with systems like API where you need to enter your passport info in advance this can become a little bit more complicated depending on the airline’s systems, but this is such a common situation that there should always be a way to do it.

Comment: Note: there are different cases, you may missed. To travel from A to B, you may use different passport when you exit A, to book a flight, and to enter in B. Also on land borders, exiting A and entering B are two different operations So, you may overthink the question. Just I recommend to book the flight with passport B (just to speed up operations: website may not know about double passports, and airport crew should double check things).

Answer (score 2):

That's generally not a good idea. Whether it's actually a real  problem depends on your specific citizenships.

Best & safest rule in my experience is

> Always enter and leave a country on the same passport

Keep in mind that the round trip contains 4 border interactions, not just 2. Leave X, enter Y, leave Y, enter X.

So if you are going from X to Y you should use BOTH passports: PassX to exit X and PassY to enter Y. On the return do it the other way around use PassY to exit Y an PassX to enter X.

You can use two passports for a single flight and Airlines are perfectly capable of handling two passports when you check in.

CAVEAT: there are over 30,000 combination of X and Y and this post is only inteded to cover the "typical" rules. Many countries don't have exit controls (US) and many countries simply don't care which passport you use.

Comment: A common exception to the rule: in general if someone with multiple nationalities has entered one of the countries of nationality using a foreign passport, it's fine to leave showing the country's own passport.

Comment: @phoog Wouldn't that cause problems if you ever try to use the foreign passport to enter or leave again, because the system will think you overstayed?